# Function of several variables which is continuous at single point

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity

Examples of functions on $\mathbb{R}$ which are continuous at a single point are well known. But what about $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ which is continuous at a single point? I tried to proceed as the one dimension case. I wanted to define $f=g_1$ on $\mathbb{Q}\times \mathbb{Q}$ and $f=g_2$ on $(\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q})\times (\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q})$ where $g_1=g_2$ has a unique solution. But in here I am leaving out $\mathbb{Q}\times (\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q})$ and $(\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q})\times \mathbb{Q}$. And I don't know what to define on those sets. Some ideas? I want to generalize such examples to $f :\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^m$. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Let $g(x)=1$ if $x\in\mathbb{Q}^2$, otherwise $-1$ and define $f(x)=|x|g(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $$\begin{array}{l|rcl}
f : & \mathbb R^n & \longrightarrow & \mathbb R \\
    & x=(x_1, \dots,x_n) & \longmapsto & \Vert x \Vert_2  \text{ if } (x_1, \dots,x_n) \in \mathbb Q^n \\
& x & \longmapsto & 0 \end{array} \text{ otherwise }$$

You'll verify that $f$ is continuous only at the origin as the set of points with all coordinates being rational is dense, as well as the set of points having all coordinate irrational. $f$ is continuous at the origin as you have for all $x \in \mathbb R^n$ $$\Vert f(x) \Vert_2 \le \Vert x \Vert_2$$

For a function defined from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R^m$ just take $(f(x),\dots,f(x))$ $m$-times.

Comment: Sorry, just read your last line , did not mean to ripoff your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think this works, for the case of $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R^m $: let $f(x): \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be continuous at just one point $x_0$. Then let $$g(x)=(f(x),f(x),..,f(x))$$. It is continuous only at $(x_0, x_0,...,x_0)$, since the projections $ f(x_0) =\pi_k (f(x_0),f(x_0),...,f(x_0))$ are continuous only at $ f(x_0) $.